# for-looping - I am having difficulty for-looping to get estimates to the second decimal of my data

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to for loop my data in R to get estimates to the nearest second decimal. I approached the solution two ways, but I am not getting a result. I am currently in a desperate state since I have been trying to do this for two days now.

nsw_psid_withtreated is my dataset

This is what I have done so far:

```
covars
#[1] "age"     "educ"    "black"   "hisp"    "married"
#[6] "re74"    "re75"    "u74"     "u75"  

nswMatrix <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = length(covars), ncol = 4))

colnames(nswMatrix) <- c("Treated", "Control", "Difference", "P-Value")

rownames(nswMatrix) <- covars

for (i in 1:length(covars)) {
     t <- t.test(nsw_psid_withtreated[nsw_psid_withtreated$nsw == 0, covars[i]], 
     nsw_psid_withtreated[nsw_psid_withtreated$nsw==1, covars[i]], na.rm=T)
     nswMatrix[covars[i], "Control"] <- round(t$estimate[1],2)
     nswMatrix[covars[i], "Treatment"] <- round(t$estimate[2],2)
     nswMatrix[covars[i], "Difference"] <- round(t$estimate[2] - t$estimate[1], 2)
     nswMatrix[covars[i], "P-Value"] <- round(t$p.value,2)
  }
Error: Must use a vector in `[`, not an object of class matrix.
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

Comment: What is `nsw_psid_withtreated`?

Comment: That is my dataset. I apologize for not being clearer!

Comment: It's pretty hard for us to diagnose the problem without being able to recreate it. Can you make a [mcve] of your dataset that reproduces your problem? If so, post it with `dput`. If you really can't include your data, posting the output of `str` for every object you use can help

Comment: Have you googled your error message / tried anything to make your parameter be a vector instead of a matrix?

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(nsw_psid_withtreated)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(nsw_psid_withtreated, 20))`.

Comment: I made up a little data set on my end and tried your code, and it seemed to work, so this definitely is one of those situations where seeing a MCVE (as @divibisan recommends) is helpful. It's possible that even in the process of making one you'll figure out what's going wrong on your end!